# Is `catch(...) { throw; }` a bad practice?

Tags: c++

While I agree that catching `...` **without rethrowing** is indeed wrong, I however believe that using constructs like this:

```
try
{
  // Stuff
}
catch (...)
{
  // Some cleanup
  throw;
}
```

Is acceptable in cases **where RAII is not applicable**. (Please, don't ask... not everybody in my company likes object-oriented programming and RAII is often seen as "useless school stuff"...)

My coworkers says that you should always know what exceptions are to be thrown and that you can always use constructs like:

```
try
{
  // Stuff
}
catch (exception_type1&)
{
  // Some cleanup
  throw;
}
catch (exception_type2&)
{
  // Some cleanup
  throw;
}
catch (exception_type3&)
{
  // Some cleanup
  throw;
}
```

Is there a well admited good practice regarding these situations?

Comment: @Pubby: Not sure this is the exact same question. The linked question is more about "Should I catch `...`" while my question focus on "Should I better catch `...` or `<specific exception>` before rethrowing"

Comment: Sorry to say that, but C++ without RAII is not C++.

Comment: So your cow-workers dismiss the technique that was invented to deal with a certain problem and then quibble about which of the inferior alternatives should be used? Sorry to say, but that seems _stupid_, no matter which way I look at it.

Comment: @FredOverflow & @sbi: I couldn't agree more. Sadly, where I work, C++ is considered as `C with classes` and most of these classes are so badly written, you can't even use them in standard containers.

Comment: "catching ... without rethrowing is indeed wrong" - you are mistaken. In `main`, `catch(...) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }` might well be right in code that isn't running under a debugger. If you don't catch, then the stack might not be unwound. It's only when your debugger detects uncaught exceptions that you want them to leave `main`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Good point indeed. But now I wonder: if an unexpected exception reaches `main()` without being handled, isn't there a programming error anyway ?

Comment: @ereOn: depends on the app. Some exceptions can be handled at best by logging the failure and exiting, so there the highest level they can be handled is the level at which the logger has been created, which quite possibly is `main`. You'd prefer that the thing thrown has a message associated with it, as with `std::exception::what()`, so you'd catch the class that defines that function and use it in the log message. Throwing something else might be a breach of your style guide, but maybe the exception didn't come from code written to your style.

Comment: ... so even if it is a "programming error", it doesn't necessarily follow that you don't want to know about it. Anyway, your colleagues are not good software professionals, so as sbi says it's very difficult to talk about how best to deal with a situation that is chronically feeble to begin with.

Comment: Fun fact -- that block of code shouldn't even be considered a *catch* block, but a *fault* block -- a block that is executed only on an exception, which is part of Microsoft's .NET Framework.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for clarifying this point. Makes much sense indeed.

Comment: @Mehrdad: what does Microsoft have to do with it? The `catch(...)` block is executed on `throw 0;`, in any implementation.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I was just saying that `fault` blocks are also a special kind of exception handler in the .NET framework. I wasn't saying that catch/throw was a Microsoft thing.

Comment: D has this construct build in with `scope(failure)`

Answer (score 198, accepted):

> My coworkers says that you should always know what exceptions are to be thrown [...]

Your coworker, I'd hate to say it, has obviously never worked on general-purpose libraries.

How in the world can a class like `std::vector` even *pretend* to know what the copy constructors will throw, while still guaranteeing exception safety?

If you always knew what the callee would do at compile-time, then polymorphism would be useless! Sometimes the *entire goal* is to abstract away what happens at a lower level, so you specifically *don't* want to know what's going on!

Comment: Actually, even if they *knew* that exceptions are to be thrown. What's the purpose of this code duplication? Unless the handling differs, I see no point in enumerating the exceptions to show off your knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: That too. Also, add to it the fact that they deprecated exception specifications because listing all possible exceptions in the code tended to cause bugs later on... it's the worst idea ever.

Comment: And what bothers me is what could be the origin of such an attitude when coupled with seeing useful and convenient technique as "useless school stuff". But well...

Comment: +1, the enumeration of all the possible options is an excellent recipe for a future failure, why on earth would someone chose doing that over `...`?

Comment: Nice answer. It could possibly benefit from mentioning that if a compiler that one has to support has a bug in area X, then using functionality from area X is not smart, at least not to use it directly. For example, given the information about the company, I would not be surprised if they used Visual C++ 6.0, which had some sillybugs in this area (like exception object destructors being called twice) -- some smaller descendants of those early bugs have survived to this day, but require careful arrangements to manifest.

Comment: @Mehrdad the worst idea was to make them runtime instead of compile time checks. I like java checked exceptions, they add documentation and remind me that I missed something (which is necessary since java uses exceptions for more than just programming errors).

Comment: @josefx: I totally agree. but, enumerating exceptions reminds me of the nightmare in java that is the checked exceptions, but scaled.

Answer (score 44):

What you seem to be caught in is the specific hell of someone trying to have their cake and eat it too.

RAII and exceptions are designed to go hand in hand. RAII is the means by which you do not *have* to write a lot of `catch(...)` statements to do cleanup. It will happen automatically, as a matter of course. And exceptions are the only way to work with RAII objects, because constructors can only succeed or throw (or put the object in an error state, but who wants that?).

A `catch` statement can do one of two things: handle an error or exceptional circumstance, or do cleanup work. Sometimes it does both, but every `catch` statement exists to do at least one of these.

`catch(...)` is incapable of doing proper exception handling. You don't know what the exception is; you can't get information about the exception. You have absolutely no information other than the fact that an exception was thrown by *something* within a certain code block. The only legitimate thing you can do in such a block is to do cleanup. And that means re-throwing the exception at the end of the cleanup.

What RAII gives you with regard to exception handling is free cleanup. If everything is RAII encapsulated properly, then everything will be properly cleaned up. You no longer need to have `catch` statements do cleanup. In which case, there is no reason to write a `catch(...)` statement.

So I would agree that `catch(...)` is mostly evil... *provisionally*.

That provision being proper use of RAII. Because without it, you *need* to be able to do certain cleanup. There's no getting around it; you have to be able to do cleanup work. You need to be able to ensure that throwing an exception will leave the code in a reasonable state. And `catch(...)` is a *vital* tool in doing so.

You cannot have one without the other. You cannot say that both RAII **and** `catch(...)` are bad. You need at least one of these; otherwise, you're not exception safe.

Of course, there's one valid-though-rare use of `catch(...)` that not even RAII can banish: getting an `exception_ptr` to forward to someone else. Typically through a `promise/future` or similar interface.

> My coworkers says that you should always know what exceptions are to be thrown and that you can always use constructs like:

Your coworker is an idiot (or just terribly ignorant). This should be immediately obvious due to how much copy-and-paste code he's suggesting that you write. The cleanup for each of those catch statements will be *exactly the same*. That's a maintenance nightmare, not to mention readability.

In short: this is the problem that RAII *was created to solve* (not that it doesn't solve other problems).

What confuses me about this notion is that it's generally backwards to how most people argue that RAII is bad. Generally, the argument goes "RAII is bad because you have to use exceptions to signal constructor failure. But you can't throw exceptions, because it's not safe and you'll have to have lots of `catch` statements to clean everything up." Which is a broken argument because RAII *solves* the problem that the lack of RAII creates.

More than likely, he's against RAII because it hides details. Destructor calls aren't immediately visible on automatic variables. So you get code that gets called implicitly. Some programmers really hate that. Apparently, to the point where they think having 3 `catch` statements, all of which do the same thing with copy-and-paste code is a better idea.

Comment: It seems you don't write code that provides **strong** exception safety guarantee. RAII helps with providing **basic** guarantee. But in order to provide strong guarantee, you have to undo some actions to revert system to the state that it had before function was called. Basic guarantee is **cleanup**, strong guarantee is **rollback**. Doing rollback is function specific. So you can't put it into "RAII". And that is when _catch-all_ block becomes handy. If you write code with strong guarantee, you use _catch-all_ much.

Comment: @anton_rh: Perhaps, but even in those cases, catch-all statements are the tool of *last resort*. The preferred tool is to do everything that throws *before* you change any state that you would have to revert on exception. Obviously you can't implement everything that way in all cases, but that's the ideal way to get the strong exception guarantee.

Answer (score 14):

Two comments, really.  The first is that while in an ideal world, you
should always know what exceptions might be thrown, in practice, if
you're dealing with third party libraries, or compiling with a Microsoft
compiler, you don't.  More to the point, however; even if you do know
exactly all of the possible exceptions, is that relevant here?  `catch
(...)` expresses the intent far better than `catch ( std::exception
const& )`, even supposing that all possible exceptions derive from
`std::exception` (which would be the case in an ideal world).  As for 
using several catch blocks, if there is no common base for all
exceptions: that is downright obfuscation, and a maintenance nightmare.
How do you recognize that all of the behaviors are identical?  And that
that was the intent?  And what happens if you have to change the
behavior (bug fix, for example)?  It's all too easy to miss one.

Comment: Actually, my coworker designed his own exception class which does **not** derive from `std::exception` and tries everyday to enforce its use amongst our codebase. My guess is that he tries to punish me for using code and external libraries he has not written himself.

Comment: @ereOn It sounds to me like your co-worker is in dire need of training.  In any case, I'd probably avoid using libraries written by him.

Comment: Templates and knowing what exceptions will be thrown go together like peanut butter and dead geckos.  Something as simple as `std::vector<>` can throw any sort of exception for pretty much any reason.

Comment: Please tell us, exactly how do you know what exception will be thrown by tomorrows bug fix further down the call tree?

Answer (score 11):

I think your co-worker has mixed up some good advice - you should only handle known exceptions in a `catch` block when you don't re-throw them.

This means:

```
try
{
  // Stuff
}
catch (...)
{
  // General stuff
}
```

Is bad because it will silently hide *any* error.

However:

```
try
{
  // Stuff
}
catch (exception_type_we_can_handle&)
{
  // Deal with the known exception
}
```

Is fine - we know what we're dealing with and don't need to expose it to the calling code.

Likewise:

```
try
{
  // Stuff
}
catch (...)
{
  // Rollback transactions, log errors, etc
  throw;
}
```

Is fine, best practice even, the code to deal with general errors should be with the code that causes them. It's better than relying on the callee to know that a transaction needs rolling back or whatever.

Answer (score 9):

Any answer of **yes** or **no** should be accompanied by a rationale of why this is so.

Saying that it is wrong simply because I've been taught that way is just blind fanaticism.

Writing the same `//Some cleanup; throw` several times, as in your example is wrong because is code duplication and that is a maintenance burden. Writing it just once is better.

Writing a `catch(...)` to silence all the exceptions is wrong because you should only handle exceptions you know how to handle, and with that wildcard you can cath more than you expect, and doing so can silence important errors.

But if you rethrow after a `catch(...)`, then the latter rationale no longer applies, as you are not actually handling the exception, so there is no reason why this should be discouraged.

Actually I've been done this for logging in sensitive functions without any problem whatsoever:

```
void DoSomethingImportant()
{
    try
    {
        Log("Going to do something important");
        DoIt();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        Log("Error doing something important: %s", e.what());
        throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        Log("Unexpected error doing something important");
        throw;
    }
    Log("Success doing something important");
}
```

Comment: Let's hope `Log(...)` cannot throw.

Answer (score 2):

I generally agree with the mood of the posts here, I really dislike the pattern of catching specific exceptions--I think that the syntax of this is still in it's infancy and not able to cope with the redundant code yet.

But since everyone is saying that, I'll pipe in with the fact that even though I use them sparingly I've often looked at one of my "catch(Exception e)" statements and said "Damn, I wish I'd called out the specific exceptions that time" because when you come in later it's often nice to know what the intention was and what the client is likely to throw at a glance.

I'm not justifying the attitude of "Always use x", just saying that occasionally it actually is nice to see them listed out and I'm sure that's why some people think it's the "Right" way to go.